# How to display a walking track or route as a Map Overlay in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit, mkoverlay

I've been trying to search the internet for a tutorial with some sample code that shows how to display a track or route as an overlay on a map. I've found some tutorials but they are for displaying circles and other shapes. I was wanting to display a point by point track.

Could anyone give me a link to a good tutorial or could someone point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

The recommended way is shown in Apples Breadcrumbs Demo App.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MKPolyline. You make an array of CLLocation with the coords of each turn point along  your route. You initialize the MKPolyline object with that array. This will draw a solid line between each point you specified. You can then adjust the Line's dashPattern and dashPhase if your points are far enough apart that you need to break up the line.

I started with an NSMutableArray of the lat,long points called points:

```
NSMutableArray *currentPoint;
int count = [points count];
double lat, long;

CLLocationCoordinate2D unitPath[count];
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < count; index++)
{
    currentPoint = [points objectAtIndex:index];

    Lat = [[currentPoint objectAtIndex:ORDER_TARGLAT] doubleValue];
    Long = [[currentPoint objectAtIndex:ORDER_TARGLONG] doubleValue];
    CLLocation *pathPoint = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:Lat longitude:Long];
    unitPath[index] = pathPoint.coordinate;
}

MKPolyline *routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:unitPath count:count];

routeLine.title = _title;
routeLine.subtitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",ID];
routeLine.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
routeLine.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
NSNumber *lineGapSize = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];
routeLine.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:lineGapSize,lineGapSize,nil];
routeLine.dashPhase = lineDashPhase;
routeLine.lineWidth = 4; 

[mapView addOverlay:routeLine]
```

P.S. ORDER_TARGLAT and ORDER_TARGLONG were just part of an enum specifying the position of items in my array. Replace as appropriate for your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
MapView* mapView = [[[MapView alloc] initWithFrame:
                         CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)] autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:mapView];

Place* home = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
home.name = @"Home";
home.description = @"Sweet home";
home.latitude = 29.860323999999990000;
home.longitude =77.893305000000050000;

Place* office = [[[Place alloc] init] autorelease];
office.name = @"Office";
office.description = @"Bad office";
office.latitude = 28.644251400000000000;
office.longitude = 77.121190500000010000;

[mapView showRouteFrom:home to:office];
```

use this one in ios 7.0